# making pagination in laravel for image

Tags: laravel

Hello for everyone I have a problem in laravel that about the showing images in one view, the problem is: I have a page that just show the images but it show all the images stored in table with specific id but I want to show some of that and have a button (show more) and when click on button it show the other images I don't know hove can I do this if someone can help me please!

This is my controller code:

```
public function listHostel()
{
    $hostels = Hostel::all();
    return view('front/khabgah_list',compact('hostels')); 
}
```

And this is my blade code:

```
@foreach($hostels as $hostel)
    @foreach($hostel->attachments as $photo)
        <div class=" col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6  col-lg-3 px-1 mt-3">
            <div class="card card-shadow custom-height-1 " style="border-radius: 0%">
                <a href="">
                    <img src="/assets-/app/media/img/blog/hostels-img/{{$photo->file_name}}"
                        class="card-img-top card-img custom-card-img-height" alt="">
                </a>
                <div class="car-body">
                    <div class="card-footer">
                        <div class="custom-circle">
                            <p class="custom-circle-text card-text">
                                <b>
                                @if($hostel->type == 1)
                                    {{ 'ذکور'}}
                                @else 
                                    {{ 'اناث' }}
                                @endif
                                </b>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="custom-prices card-text text-left"> کرایه فی ماه
                            : {{$hostel->remark }}  
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

Pagination is likely what you're looking for. Change your controller to:

```
public function listHostel()
{
    $hostels = Hostel::all()->paginate(5);
    return view('front/khabgah_list',compact('hostels')); 
}
```

Then you can get the links in your Blade template:

```
{{ $hostels->links() }}
```

You might need to change it a bit to work for your specific situation. The documentation gives some more info: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/pagination